# Cannot mount network drive on boot despite _netdev,x-systemd.device-timeout=60 in fstab as well as wait for network on boot

Tags: mount, fstab

I understand that this has been asked many times but the stuff that has worked for everyone else does not seem to work for me. I am trying to mount a network drive (HDD connected to SHIELD TV Pro) on boot. My fstab entry is as follows:

`//{IP Address of Shield}/SHIELD_NAS /mnt/SHIELD_HDD cifs _netdev,x-systemd.device-timeout=60,credentials=/home/nas_credentials,uid=sarp,gid=sarp,forceuid,forcegid,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

I also turned on wait for network before boot and still the drive does not mount on boot. I am successfully able to mount the drive using `sudo mount -a`.

When I reboot, the drive shows up in file manager but it is not mounted. I also looked at the logs and it seems like it is only attempting to mount once, despite having `x-systemd.device-timeout=60` in the fstab entry (maybe I am understanding that wrong).

Please help I have been scouring a billion different forums for hours and my head is hurting...

Comment: AFAIK uid gid need to be numeric.

Comment: Post output of findmnt when mounting manually.

Comment: There are no issues with the mount being mounted correctly. When I look at `ls -la` I can see that the owner user and the group is sarp. Where is findmnt?

Comment: I moved the mount point to outside the home folder into /mnt/SHIELD_HDD and the problem still persists.